# upload file exceeds Wordpress / Apache / Linux AMI 2

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, apache

Currently I'm trying to upload `zip` file of plugin in my Wordpress site

But this gaves me an error like this

`The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.`

Tried to update my `php.ini` directives

Like

```
 memory_limit = 999M
 upload_max_filesize = 100000M
 post_max_size = 999M
```

and did this `sudo systemctl restart httpd`

But seems not working.

This is the file that I want to upload

[image]

with size of 2.15mb

While the limit is 2mb

[image]

and this is the error

[image]

Tried to follow this but not working 
https://phoenixnap.com/kb/fix-the-uploaded-file-exceeds-the-upload-max-filesize-directive-in-php-ini-wordpress

Comment: did you check is there any php.in file in your project folder?

Comment: Is there anyway you can validate using phpinfo in your browser that the setting was changed in the ini?

Comment: I found a php.ini in my wordpress folder tried to change it but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to update upload redirectives in /etc/php.ini

```
 post_max_size 200M
 upload_max_filesize 200M
 memory_limit 300M
 max_execution_time 259200
 max_input_time 259200
 session.gc_maxlifetime 1200
```

and restart the php and apache

```
 sudo systemctl restart php-fpm.service
 sudo systemctl restart httpd.service
```